# Faster Workflow

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table (Table 1) with a whole bunch of well data (versions, MD, HD, etc.) and I want to create another table (Table 2) that will only show the data for the well I am interested in.

I have it set up where you select the well using a drop down list. Then I want Table 2 to be populated with four values for each of the iterations that show up in Table 1....

I tried using vlookup but was having issues when a well had multiple versions. And I also tried using an advanced filter.

#### Screenshot of the spreadsheet

[image: Screenshot of the spreadsheet]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vlookup from different tables dependent on a drop down list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32049209/vlookup-from-different-tables-dependent-on-a-drop-down-list)

Comment: You need to be specific about what you've tried and what you can't get right.

Comment: I first tried using vlookup but some of the wells only have one entry and others have two. (Most will have around 3-6 soon). The Vlookup worked perfectly for the wells with one entry but when there were two entries, the vlookup was just repeating the first entry.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with using advanced filters so I could never get it to work. I am not even sure if that is best method for this. I was googling my issue and someone suggested it in one of the threads I was reading.

Answer (score 0):

Let's solve this using a helper column. First, assume column A will be used to the left of your table, to show the row number which each one of these is found in.

A5 would have the following formula:

```
=MATCH($C$1,K:K,0)
```

This shows us the row number that Well1 is first matched at. Then A6 and copied down would have the formula:

```
=A5+MATCH(B6,OFFSET(K1,A5,0,COUNT(M:M),1),0)
```

This uses OFFSET to create a new range, starting at the cell immediately below the previous match for Well1, and then uses MATCH to find what row that occurs.

So now, column A will always show the row number to pull data from. The rest is simply using the INDEX function to pull from your desired columns. For example, the data in column C pulls the iteration from column L, and can be pulled through formula like so, in cell C5 and copied to the right / down:

```
=INDEX(L:L,$A5)
```

Comment: @Tony If this worked for you, would you mind clicking the 'Accept' button to the left of my answer, to mark this question as complete?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is appropriately normalized, you might be better off with a Pivot Table. This would give you the option of filtering by Well ID.

Answer (score 0):

To use a Advanced filter you will need to create a worksheet event.  Place this in the code for the sheet on which you want the data.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
    Dim dataRng As Range
    Dim critRng As Range
    Dim CpyToRng As Range
    Dim cpytoarr() As Variant
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set dataRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
    End With
    With Me
        .Range("CC1") = .Cells(1, 1).Value
        .Range("CC2") = "'=" & .Cells(2, 1).Value
        Set critRng = .Range("CC1:CC2")
        Set CpyToRng = .Range(.Cells(6, 1), .Cells(6, 1).End(xlToRight))
    End With
    Debug.Print dataRng.Address
    Debug.Print critRng.Address
    Debug.Print CpyToRng.Address

    dataRng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=critRng, CopyToRange:=CpyToRng, _
    Unique:=False
    critRng.ClearContents
End If

End Sub
```

How this works.  This assumes the data is on Sheet1 and starts in "A1" with no blanks in column A or the last row:

[image]

On Sheet2 set it up like this:

[image]

It is important that the header rows on sheet2 are name identical to the headers on sheet1.

Now every time that the value changes in A2 on sheet 2, your drop down, the requisite data will appear below row 6.